# system boots directly to windows without giving boot options

Tags: boot, bios, windows-10

I used to have <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> options during the boot process before entering Windows. After I installed Windows 10, the boot process appears to be locked. I can access the BIOS only through the recovery and firmware options in Windows. I cannot boot my laptop with a pen drive or DVD.

I need the ability to boot from a pen drive because I want to flash my BIOS. How can I recover my boot options? I tried disabling secure boot in BIOS, but it didn’t change anything.

The laptop is a Lenovo S410P.

Comment: Which computer ?

Comment: what manufacturer made the laptop

Comment: Lenovo. S410P. i had boot options before. am not sure why its not spearing anymore. i guess it happened after upgrade to windows10

Comment: Is fast start-up enabled in Power options -  Choose what the power buttons do ?

Comment: i've no idea but maybe this helps  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/windows-10-enterprise-i-cannot-get-into-the-bios/10562f96-f0c0-496e-927e-711dcb0c1938?auth=1

Comment: it was enabled. i disabled it. but still i dont get F2,F12,.. any options. directly boots into windows

Comment: I remember times when without a keyboard a computer wouldn't boot, I don't know if that's still the case. i'm curious what happens if you remove the keyboard? Maybe if you do that, you can see what keys it lets you push, though I guess you won't be able to push them

Comment: that wont be easy to remove the keyboard in my laptop :D

Comment: besides losing the functionality, in addition, has it only removed the writing about pushing F2/F12,etc or has the whole BIOS screen changed in any way? (I ask because maybe we can get information like what the BIOS screen looked like before/after - if any difference), which may help in the googling for a solution   (and as a side note, just to state the obvious just in case.. try Del and F10 and F11 too. And less obvious, try pause/break, see if that pauses the BIOS screen)

Comment: bios is exactly same as before. i tried many times by changing bios and booting again, for example i tried legacy instead of UEFI, i tried disable enable secure boot. but nothing changed

Comment: I think W10 overwriten your MBR sector. The linux is there but you dont have GRUB anymore. You need to install grub from live linux and use some tool to generate GRUB entries after searching for installed systems.

Comment: i mistyped. edited now. its windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Here is what fixed it for me. First in Windows 10 recovery, I restarted to UEFI firmware. Then in BIOS, I changed UEFI option to legacy. The next time I boot, I got two options of <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>.